# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart Warning

Tags: debian, apache-2.2

When I run the /etc/init.d/apache2 restart command to restart the webserver, I get this warning:

```
Restarting web server: apache2[Sat Jan 09 23:27:46 2010] [warn] VirtualHost 188.40.153.18
5:443 overlaps with VirtualHost 188.40.153.185:443, the first has precedence, perhaps you
 need a NameVirtualHost directive
[Sat Jan 09 23:27:46 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost 188.40.153.190:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Sat Jan 09 23:27:46 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost 188.40.153.190:443 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting .[Sat Jan 09 23:27:48 2010] [warn] VirtualHost 188.40.153.185:443 overlaps w
ith VirtualHost 188.40.153.185:443, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirt
ualHost directive
[Sat Jan 09 23:27:48 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost 188.40.153.190:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Sat Jan 09 23:27:48 2010] [warn] NameVirtualHost 188.40.153.190:443 has no VirtualHosts
.
```

There is an IP on my server that has no virtual host assigned. I guess that is not harmful because Apache works fine.

Or should I try to fix it?

Comment: You actually get three warnings; one is important, the other two are innocuous.  Which one did you want to ask about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to do anything about this. It just means that apache noticed the IP. Request would go to the defualt virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

you have two virtual host configured for 188.40.153.185:443. This confuses apache and he only accepts the first one. You should merge these vhosts or change the ip for the seconds vhost, depending on what you want to achieve.

Or if your are using name based virtual hosting (possible with ssl, but not the best way) you need to add a `NameVirtualHost` directive as one of the error messages says.